# music bot stopping music entirely instead of skipping one song discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, ffmpeg, python-3.6, discord.py

When i use my skip command, my program stops playing music, instead of skipping a song.
Here's the code:

```
queues = {}
players = {}
opts = {
            'default_search': 'auto',
            'quiet': True,
        }
voice_states = {}

class voice:
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.command(pass_context=True)
    async def skip(self, ctx):
        id = ctx.message.server.id
        players[id].stop()

    @commands.command(
        pass_context=True
    )
    async def play(self, ctx, url):
        server = ctx.message.server
        channel = ctx.message.author.voice.voice_channel
        try:
            await self.client.join_voice_channel(channel)
        except:
            print(" ")
        if server.id not in players or players[server.id].is_done():
            server = ctx.message.server
            voice_client = self.client.voice_client_in(server)
            player = await voice_client.create_ytdl_player(url, after=lambda: queue(server.id), ytdl_options=opts)
            players[server.id] = player
            await self.client.say('Now Playing ' )
            player.start()
        else:
            server = ctx.message.server
            voice_client = self.client.voice_client_in(server)
            player = await voice_client.create_ytdl_player(url, after=lambda: queue(server.id),  ytdl_options=opts)

            if server.id in queues:
                queues[server.id].append(player)
            else:
                queues[server.id] = [player]
            await self.client.say('Now Playing ' )
            await self.client.say('Video queued.')

    def queue(self, id):
        if queues[id] != []:
            player = queues[id].pop(0)
            players[id] = player
            player.start()

def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(voice(client))
```

i receive no error codes,
just no queue.
Fixes to my code or own solutions are appreciated.
Sorry, for long code, but you need all the context

Comment: `queues` is a dict, but `queues(server.id)` is trying to call it like a function.  What do you intend this to do?

Comment: queues is supposed to play the next song in the queue of that specific server after the first song is finished, i changed the () to []

Comment: ffmpeg may be used here, but the issue involves the python code

Comment: thanks for your insight, will edit title

Comment: Again, what do you expect `after=lambda: queues[server.id]` to do? It's a callback without any side effects.  Are you trying to call the `queue` function?

Comment: i'm trying to call the `queue` function

Comment: It looks like you should be able to add a call to `queue(ctx.message.server.id)` in `skip` to start the next song.

Comment: Like this when i use the play command twice (if used twice it should queue the second song), it plays both songs at the same time and ffmpeg crashes

Comment: I as well experienced this problem when I started, I currently don't have any code to give as a answer since Im rewriting my bot currently from the ground up. Ill give you one soon though.

Comment: I figured it out, thanks tho